# Postman POST request stuck on "sending request" (MongoDB and Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I've been trying to make CRUD operations with node.js and MongoDB, but after sending a POST request on Postman, it just seems to be stuck on "sending request".

For the postman request, the url which i use to make the POST request is :
http://localhost:3000/api/employee/store

In the body section, i've selected raw -> JSON format

```
{
    "name" : "testname",
    "designation" : "Software Engineer",
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "1233123",
    "age" : 320
}
```

Below is my code :

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Working with mongoDB Db
const morgan = require('morgan'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //Get submitted input 
const app = express();


const EmployeeRoute = require('./routes/employee')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb',{useNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
const db = mongoose.connection


db.on('error', (err) =>{
    console.log(err);
})

db.once('open',()=>{
    console.log("Database Connection Established!");
})



app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended : true
}));

app.use(express.json);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + PORT);
});

app.use('/api/employee', EmployeeRoute)
```

EmployeeController.js

```
const Employee = require('../models/Employee')

//Show the list of Employees
const index = (req,res,next)=>{
    Employee.find()

    .then(response =>{
        res.json({
            response
        })
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        res.json({
            message : 'An error has occured!'
        })
    })
}

//Show single employee
const show = (req,res,next)=>{
    let employeeID = req.body.employeeID
    Employee.findById(employeeID)
    .then(response =>{
        res.json({
            response
        })
    })

    .catch(error=>{
        res.json({
            message : "An error has occured!"
        })
    })
}


//Function to store employee details
const store = (req,res,next) =>{
    let employee = new Employee({
        name : req.body.name,
        designation: req.body.designation,
        email : req.body.email,
        phone : req.body.phone,
        age : req.body.age
    })

    employee.save()

    .then(response=>{
        res.json({
            message : "Employee added sucessfully!"
        })
    })

    .catch(error=>{
        res.json({
            message : "An error has occured!"
        })
    })
}

//Function to update employee
const update = (req,res,next) => { 
   let employeeID = req.body.employeeID

   let updatedData = {
    name : req.body.name,
    designation: req.body.designation,
    email : req.body.email,
    phone : req.body.phone,
    age : req.body.age
   }

    Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeID, {$set : updatedData})

    .then(() => {
        res.json({
            message : "Employee updated sucessfully!"
        })
    })

    .catch(error=>{
        res.json({
            message : "An error has occured!"
        })
    })
}

//Delete an Employee
const destroy= (req,res,next) =>{
    let employeeID = req.body.employeeID
    Employee.findByIdAndRemove(employeeID)

    .then(() =>{
        req.json({
            message : 'Employee successfully deleted!'
        })
    })

    .catch(error =>{
        req.json({
            message : "An error has occured!"
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    index, show, store, update, destroy
}
```

employee.js (model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const employeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type : String
    },
    designation: {
        type: String 
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    }
}, {timestamps : true})

const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema)
module.exports = Employee
```

employee.js(route)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const EmployeeController = require('../controllers/EmployeeController')

router.get('/', EmployeeController.index)
router.post('/show', EmployeeController.show)
router.post('/store', EmployeeController.store)
router.post('/update', EmployeeController.update)
router.post('/delete', EmployeeController.destroy)

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to it, just 1 mistake in this line:

```
app.use(express.json);
```

It should be: `app.use(express.json());`

The documentation page, in case you need it: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: Ahh, such a silly mistake on my side. It's working now, Thanks!